# Turning a nested select into a left join, with a max(date) condition

Tags: date, max, left-join, subquery

This is seemingly way too expensive. Can someone help me turn alter to fit a left join? The max(dateprocessed) syntax is killing me.

```
SELECT a.container, a.blnumber, a.bookingnumber, a.dateprocessed 
      FROM tracking_buffer_archive a, (SELECT container, blnumber, bookingnumber, max(dateprocessed) 
      AS max_date FROM tracking_buffer_archive GROUP BY container) b
      WHERE 
      a.bookingnumber = '26007465580A'
      and a.container = b.container 
      and a.blnumber = b.blnumber
      AND a.dateprocessed = b.max_date
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What RDBMS is this ??

Comment: It's myphp/mysql. I figured this out last week, but haven't had time to post my answer. I'll do that soon. Thanks for looking!